# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring, autorelease, stringwithformat

Could someone help me with code below? Randomly get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in this loop. I guess there something wrong with [NSString stringWithFormat:....], but don't understand why and don't know how to fix. Thank you very much.

```
for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
     {
    for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
    {

        CGRect tileFrame=CGRectMake(i*tileSize, j*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize  );
        UILabel * t=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:tileFrame];


        t.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",j*row+i];




         ///If there is a crashing ,it always stop at here, right after the [NSString stringWithFormat:.....]
         t.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];




        //NSString * temps=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",j*row+i ];
        //t.text=temps;

       [myView addSubview:t];

       [t release];

    }
}
```

BTW, I read some post online, I was told to  do it in the way below can fix the problem. I'm not sure about this, why need to retain an autorelease object when this object is still in its scope. And more important shouldn't I release the retain object somewhere? Otherwise there will cause a memory leaking.

replace

```
 t.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",j*row+i];
```

with:

```
 NSString * temps=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",j*row+i ];
[temps retain];
 t.text=temps;
```

Comment: Where it is exactly crashing? Without crash log, it would be difficult for anyone to tell answer.

Comment: That crazy double for loop might have something to do with it.

Comment: such "crazy" double for loops are used in tens of thousands of apps. It's actually pretty standard if you do something that involves columns and rows. m)

Comment: And I'm pretty sure your app is not crashing because of this code.

Comment: As @MatthiasBauch said, this is not the source of your crash.

Comment: Like what I said this crashing happens randomly. The app always stopped exactly after the [NSString stringWithFormat: ]. I really cannot figure out what's wrong with this code . It's quite simple and standard. There might be something else wrong with my code .I'll read the memory management article one more time to think about this and check my code one more time. Thanks for all your comments. – Lynn just now edit

Answer (score 0):

i have tested it in my device and it is not crashing .

i have added 't' in self.view , i think there may be a problem with myView

Comment: Like what I said this crashing happens randomly. The app always stopped exactly after the [NSString stringWithFormat:   ]. I really cannot figure out what's wrong with this code . It's quite simple and standard.  There might be something else wrong with my code .I'll read the memory management article one more time to think about this and check my code one more time. Thanks for all your comments.

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you work with an object which was released previously. Try to setup these settings:[image]
They are in Project >> Edit Scheme >> Arguments

Then place the console output here.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about this? What's the difference if set up these settings. I mean the NSZombieEnabled to YES and MallocStackLoggingNoCompact to 1.

Comment: If you're in Xcode 4, the Zombies checkbox is in the Scheme settings--click "Edit Scheme" from the scheme popup (click the left-hand side of that..), select the "Run" row on the left in the sheet, then the Diagnostics header, and then click the "Enable Zombie Objects" checkbox and "Malloc Stack" under Logging. Here's a wiki page I made (forever ago!) about what you do next: http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease

Comment: I wanted to post the similar link but I have found a page on Russian only